# Save Excel-data with Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, save

Here's my problem: 
I want to open an Excel file which serves as a template. This file should be edited and then saved. The name is a variable, so it should always change. I.e. variable A that changes all the time.

With the function [xlsread] I open the template and with the function [xlswrite] I can change it as I like and it works without problems. The problem is I can't save the file separately, that means that after editing the template I only get 1 file back, but I want to keep the template and get an edited file so I can use the template again. I could not find a way to save the edited Excel file.

Please help me

Comment: Can't you use a different filename when calling `xlswrite`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your thinking. `xlsread` reads the whole file and keeps it in memory. When you use `xlswrite` your variables from memory are written to a file, with no link to the file read (as long as you change the file name).

That having said, please note that Matlab recommends to use `writetable`/`writematrix`/`writecell` instead of `xlswrite`. The same is true for `xlsread` => `readtable`/`readmatrix`/`readcell`.